# How do I push_back RectangleShapes into a 2d vector

Tags: c++

I'm not able to push_back RectangleShape t into my Cboard 2d vector. Also, How do I know the location I'm pushing back to? I'm guessing it would be cBoard[0][1]>>cBoard[0][2]...>>cBoard[1][0].

```
class board
{
public:
int x;
int y;
vector <vector <RectangleShape> > cBoard;

create(int,int);
void drawTile(RenderWindow &window, int, int);
};

board::create(int x, int y){
    cBoard = vector <vector <RectangleShape> >(x, vector< RectangleShape >
(y, tile()));
    int counter = 0;
    RectangleShape t;

    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
        counter = 0;
        if(i % 2 == 1){
            counter = 1;
                }
    for(int ii = 0; ii < x; ii++){
        if(counter % 2 == 0){
            t.setFillColor(Color::Red);
            cBoard.push_back(t);
            cout << "red";
            counter++;
        }
        else if(counter % 2 == 1){
            t.setFillColor(Color::Green);
            cBoard.push_back(t);
            cout << "green";
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Post an [mcve].  And if the issue is inserting values in a vector, why are you showing all of this irrelevant code such as filing colors, `i%2, etc.

Comment: Main problem here is the fact that `cBoard` is a vector of vectors of Rectangles which makes this `cBoard.push_back(t);` invalid since `t` is `RectangleShape`.

Comment: The second issue is that the vector is already populated with x "rows" and y "columns" before you do any `push_back` calls.  You really should start with a small application to first get familiar how to handle a vector of vectors [such as this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cbe9fe04392c040).  Any issues (and the code posted has the issue I brought up), you can use that code and post it here, as it is a [mcve].  Stuff with filling colors, doing modulus calculations, etc. is not needed.